# Can't get rid of borders in Awesome WM

Tags: awesome-wm

I'm trying to make a task list popup with transparency, but I ran into a problem with the borders. Can't find a way to remove the black bars around the popup.

I tried border_width = 0 and theme.border_width = 0 but it just doesn't work.

[Popup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rrulw.png)

Comment: Are you using some composite manager? Something like `xcompmgr`, `compiz`, ...? Those black bars look like some kind of shadow to me like composite managers draw them.

Comment: Yes, I'm using picom. That was the problem. I didn't know they can draw borders. Thank you!

Comment: Any idea on how to exclude the shadows from the popup?

Comment: Not really, but https://github.com/yshui/picom/blob/cd50596f0ed81c0aa28cefed62176bd6f050a1c6/picom.sample.conf#L6-L11 suggests that you want to set `type = "desktop"`. `xprop` should be able to tell you whether that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Uli I managed to remove the borders (shadows) of the popup.

The problem was that the picom compositor was creating shadows around the popup.

Making the widget type = "desktop" makes picom ignore it.

[github.com/yshui/picom/blob/...](https://github.com/yshui/picom/blob/cd50596f0ed81c0aa28cefed62176bd6f050a1c6/picom.sample.conf#L6-L11)

> Enabled client-side shadows on windows. Note desktop windows
> (windows with '_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DESKTOP') never get shadow,
> unless explicitly requested using the wintypes option.